# How do you clear a pending interrupt on PLIC without performing a claim?

Tags: riscv

I'm trying to write a PLIC and I'm stuck on whether it's possible to clear an interrupt without performing a claim.

Is it possible to clear an interrupt by removing an interrupt's cause (ex: context 3 is no longer trying to cause an interrupt) without doing a claim?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: According to official PLIC doc, "A pending bit in the PLIC core can be cleared by setting the associated enable bit then performing a claim." As far as I know, there's no other ways.